# Targeting item in Array of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the following array of objects. I am trying to target one of them and get the array data.

So if I want to target `5659313586569216`, I'd like to be able to grab that array that's connected to it.

In short, I'd like to grab the `[item]` from by either saying I want to grab it from `5659313586569216` or `5722646637445120`.

Could anyone shed some guidance?

```
Array ( 
    [0] => GDS\Entity Object (
        [str_kind:GDS\Entity:private] => Item List
        [str_key_id:GDS\Entity:private] => 5659313586569216
        [str_key_name:GDS\Entity:private] => 
        [mix_ancestry:GDS\Entity:private] => 
        [arr_data:GDS\Entity:private] => Array ( [item] => 123 )
    )

    [1] => GDS\Entity Object (
        [str_kind:GDS\Entity:private] => Item List
        [str_key_id:GDS\Entity:private] => 5722646637445120
        [str_key_name:GDS\Entity:private] =>
        [mix_ancestry:GDS\Entity:private] =>
        [arr_data:GDS\Entity:private] => Array ( [item] => 456 )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ease with regex over `serialize()`.
If you can show the result of:

```
$arr = array(...);
echo(serialize($arr));
```

I can write for you regex there to extract the name of argument.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation, you may be able to keep a reference to newly created entities by their string key id, and use that later on for fast lookups:

```
namespace GDS;

class Entity
{
    private $str_key_id;
    private $arr_data;
    // ...

    // Array of Entity instances, indexed by their string key id
    static $entities_by_str_key_id = Array();

    public function __construct($str_key_id, $arr_data)
    {
        $this->str_key_id = $str_key_id;
        $this->arr_data   = $arr_data;

        // Keep reference by id
        self::$entities_by_str_key_id[$str_key_id] = $this;
    }

    public function getArrDataItem()
    {
        return $this->arr_data['item'];
    }

    public static function getArrDataItemByStrKeyId($str_key_id)
    {
        return self::$entities_by_str_key_id[$str_key_id]->getArrDataItem();
    }
}

// Create a few entities
$entities = array(
    new Entity(5659313586569216, array("item" => 123)),
    new Entity(5722646637445120, array("item" => 456)),
);

// Get array data item by string key id
print Entity::getArrDataItemByStrKeyId(5659313586569216) . PHP_EOL;
print Entity::getArrDataItemByStrKeyId(5722646637445120) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
123
456
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach to what you're after if you decide to escape the actual object data type. Basically its arrays encapsulated in arrays and then using foreach to extract elements out of the arrays.

```
$db=array(
    "5659313586569216"=>array(
    "Item Name"=>"Some Item",
    "Item Country"=>"USA",
    "Item Code"=>"123"
    ),
    "5722646637445120"=>array(
    "Item Name"=>"Some Other Item",
    "Item Price"=>"$100",
    "Item Code"=>"456"
    )
);
foreach ($db as $itemcode=>$itemdata){
    echo "For Item long code number ".$itemcode."...\n";
    foreach ($itemdata as $itemfield=>$itemvalue){
        echo "The ".$itemfield." is ".$itemvalue."...\n";
    }
}
```

Add the following line at the top of the code if you're using a web browser for better appearance:

```
header("content-type: text/plain",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
// $entities is the array of Entity instances
$id = 5659313586569216;
list($entity) = array_filter(
    $entities,
    function($e) use ($id) { return $e->str_key_id == $id; }
);
echo "Item for $id = " . $entity->arr_data["item"] . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Item for 5659313586569216 = 123
```

For clarity, the private str_key_id and arr_data members are accessed as public members in the example above. The code should of course be changed to use their accessors, like get_str_key_id() or getStrKeyId() or getId() or whatever the GDS\Entity class provides.